# How to search for one email in a repository of .pst files

Tags: ms-office, outlook-2010, pst, file-search

I downloaded a script that automatically backed up my dad's Outlook (2010 version) every morning at 6:00am and he now has a bundle of the .pst files each containing thousands and thousands of emails.

Somewhere along the way (I don't know where), he lost a bunch of emails or deleted them or something. I'm really not sure where they went.

Regardless, other than opening each .pst file, can I sort through the folder they are all in to locate the SPECIFIC email that I want? What is the best method for doing this?

Thank you all so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contents of a .pst file cannot be searched -- they must be opened manually.